# How can I select elements from my other html files

Tags: javascript, html

Forgive my ignorance I am new to web development,
I have a simple budget app that gets information from the user. I want to display this information in another html page. But when I try to select the specific dom element it throws me an error that it cannot find it.

I thought my problem will be solved using webpack. I bundled all the js file together and gave it to all my html pages but I still cannot access my element.

```
//My controller got the data from the user and created an instance of the Budget object and gave the information to my displayincome function.

displayIncome(newBudget.id, newBudget.date, newBudget.description, newBudget.value);

//my displayIncome then tries to insert this data to the .item-container div.

export const displayIncome = (id, date, description, value) => {
  const markup = `
           <div class="item" href="#${id}">
            <div class= "item__date">
              ${date}
            </div>
            <div class="item__description">
              ${description}
            </div>
            <div class="item__value">
              ${value}
              <div class="item__delete">
                <div class="item__delete--btn"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        `;
  document.querySelector('.item-container').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', markup);
};
```

Expected to insert the information to the div.
Actual results gets my this error:

﻿
bundle.51d4e9d….js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null
    at bundle.51d4e9d….js:1
    at c (bundle.51d4e9d….js:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.document.querySelector.addEventListener.e (bundle.51d4e9d….js:1)

Comment: That error is saying `querySelector('.item-container')` returned `null`, meaning there is no such element in your current page

Comment: Yes I understood that. But what I am trying to figure out is how  to select an element from another page

Comment: You can't refer to elements in other documents from another simply using query selectors. There isn't really any way to do this at all, so what makes you think you can? I can probably give an answer that might help, but can you clarify a bit about what you are trying to do here?

Comment: I'm getting data from a page. What I want to do is insert this data to a dom element  in another page which is called item-contakner. Do I need ajax? I guess I'm missing something fundamental here. I was thinking because webpack bundles all the javascript into one file and all html pages share the same js script then the variables are available for all the html pages. I guess this is an incorrect assumption?

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that include bundle.js after element .item-container or using it after event "DOMContentLoaded".

example:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
   displayIncome(newBudget.id, newBudget.date, newBudget.description, newBudget.value);
});
```

There one more problem using displayIncome before initialization in you code.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more. I dont fully understand what you mean